# Can type hints of the class be used in class functions?

Tags: python

Is it possible to use type annotations in methods of a class for the same class?
Suppose I have a vector class, this class supports the `__add__`.

Something like this:

```
class Vector:
    def __add__(self, other: Vector):
        #blah blah
```

Of course this doesn't work. Are there other similar methods or any workarounds?

Comment: Is your question whether it is possible to add such a type annotation, or whether it is possible to use such a type annotation to "make sure the parameter is of the same class"?  As mentioned in some answers, type annotations don't enforce anything, so even if you could make such an annotation, it wouldn't "make sure" of that.

Comment: I misunderstood type hints, I thought it was a mechanism which could enforce types. However for documentation it can be useful. I will edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type annotations are something that is intended to help the people reading the code, static analysis tools and documentation tools. It doesn't actually enforce anything even if it were possible to execute the code (I mean without the `NameError`) you have.

It's generally considered bad style in python to actually enforce a particular class, you generally expect a particular interface (like having a particular attribute):

```
class Vector(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x, self.y = x, y
    def __add__(self, other):
        try:
            return Vector(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)
        except AttributeError:  # the other had no x or y attribute
            raise TypeError('cannot add Vector to {}'.format(type(other)))
```

Or just omit the `try` and `except` and let it fails with the `AttributeError`:

```
class Vector(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x, self.y = x, y
    def __add__(self, other):
        return Vector(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)
```

That doesn't have an informative exception message (do you need one?) but it does still fail when the `other` has no `x` or `y` attribute.

---

If I misunderstood your question and it was only about "how to add the typehint" then you just wrap it as string (called "Forward referencing"):

```
class Vector(object):
    def __add__(self, other: 'Vector'):
        ...
```

They even have a similar example in PEP 484:

> ### [Forward references](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references)
>
> When a type hint contains names that have not been defined yet, that definition may be expressed as a string literal, to be resolved later.
>
> A situation where this occurs commonly is the definition of a container class, where the class being defined occurs in the signature of some of the methods. For example, the following code (the start of a simple binary tree implementation) does not work:
>
> ```
> class Tree:
>     def __init__(self, left: Tree, right: Tree):
>         self.left = left
>         self.right = right
> ```
>
> To address this, we write:
>
> ```
> class Tree:
>     def __init__(self, left: 'Tree', right: 'Tree'):
>         self.left = left
>         self.right = right
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if `other` is a Vector type:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, Vector):
        ##do the add
    else:
        raise TypeError('other is not a Vector Type')
```

Comment: So there is no other way of doing this?

Comment: @LucasCrijns what is wrong with doing it this way?

Comment: It looks cumbersome to implement this for every operator function in a class, so I thought that maybe there is a leaner way of doing this